# how to add admin_init in my plugin so that contributors can upload images

Tags: wordpress

I Have plugin called MyPlugin written by me. i have a yes or no radio button , If the option is yes means it should allow contributor to upload image and no means it should not allow.

This is the code to allow contributor to upload image

```
if ( current_user_can('contributor') && !current_user_can('upload_files') )
    add_action('admin_init', 'allow_contributor_uploads');
function allow_contributor_uploads() {
    $contributor = get_role('contributor');
    $contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
} 
// this is the code to remove if the capabilities if it is added

if ( current_user_can('contributor') && current_user_can('upload_files') )
    add_action('admin_init', 'remove_contributor_upload');
function remove_contributor_upload(){
    $con = get_role('contributor');
    $con->remove_cap('upload_files');
}
```

i need a help where should i put this code in the plugin, i tried it but i got error as

```
Error in wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1059
```

Comment: What was the error, and what version of WordPress is this on?

Comment: Wordpress Version is 3.0.1 and the error is Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()

Comment: Why are you running such an old version of WordPress?

Comment: @webaware we built the site some two years ago, it is a multisite with 10,000 users so upgrading it may take long time, we are working on upgrading it!

Comment: No worries, you get that :) best of luck with the upgrades (I hope you test your backups!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling functions that can't be called before init(), so they are undefined (specifically, wp_get_current_user() is defined in wp-includes/pluggable.php and that isn't loaded until after all plugins have been loaded). You need to rearrange your code to check user privileges **after** admin_init is called, e.g.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'allow_contributor_uploads');
function allow_contributor_uploads() {
    if ( current_user_can('contributor') && !current_user_can('upload_files') ) {
        $contributor = get_role('contributor');
        $contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
    }
}
// this is the code to remove if the capabilities if it is added

add_action('admin_init', 'remove_contributor_upload');
function remove_contributor_upload(){
    if ( current_user_can('contributor') && current_user_can('upload_files') ) {
        $con = get_role('contributor');
        $con->remove_cap('upload_files');
    }
}
```

NB: just solving your error problem here, have not looked at the logic of what you're doing!

Comment: @webware these two codes are to allow and prevent contributors to upload image!